# how to reduce memory occupied by bitmap in android

Tags: android

how to reduce memory occupied by bitmap in android. will options.insamplesize of bitmap reduce the memory consumed by bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `opt.inSampleSize` with proper scale will reduce memory consumption if used in BitmapFactory.

Also, you should set `opt.inPurgeable = true` to allow bitmaps to be purged.

And finally, you should call `bmp.recycle()` when you don't need the bitmap anymore.

Comment: It should be the power of 2, for faster/easier decoding.

Comment: but the in sample size is reducing the clarity of the image

Comment: Of course, because it is resizing images by inSampleSize (512 x 512 image decoded with `opt.inSampleSize = 4` will became 128 x 128, so it will be 1/16 size of the orginal picture).

Comment: is there any way to keep clarity the same and reduce the memory consumption

Comment: does opt.inpurgeable help in reducing memory consumption. does it really work.

Comment: You can check that by printing used native memory before & after bitmap allocation : `Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`

Answer (score 0):

Use Util class that Contain the Virtual SD card Memory to Store the Image. . .